# Adobe Illustrator CS6: Selecting an individual segment of an illustration

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, shapes, cs6

I am making an illustration of a hot air balloon in Adobe Illustrator CS6. I am following this [online tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=onKRqmU9KeM).

I have the following:

[image]

To get to this stage I have followed these steps in the tutorial:

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the above steps I have selected the entire hot air balloon, and then applied the Divide tool from the Pathfinder panel to the entire selection. I have then ungrouped the selection so that the individual segments can be coloured in.

However, I am trying to also colour in the individual segments at the bottom of the balloon. When I select the bottom portion I get the following:

[image]

In the video tutorial, each individual segment can be selected:

[image]

These stages of the tutorial occur between 2:30-2:49 min in the video. I am sure that no other steps were taken after using the Divide Tool and ungrouping the selection in the video. However, I am not sure how to select each individual segment at the bottom of the balloon like in the video.

Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: Looks like your selection is a group.  Have you tried ungrouping it?  You might not be able to see this in the tutorial if the author used a keyboard shortcut.  The shortcut to ungroup is Shift+Ctrl+G (or Shift+Command+G on Mac).

Comment: I thought of that, but the OP does say he did ungroup: _"I have then ungrouped the selection..."_.

Comment: I have ungrouped the selection, so I am not sure why am getting the result.

Answer (score 0):

The author is coloring in the fills of those shapes, not the segments on the side.

To use color on the 'segments' (or strokes in AI language), you need to switch to the stroke by hitting <kbd>X</kbd> on the keyboard.

Also a good tip is to use the <kbd>A</kbd> (Direct Selection Tool) to select individual objects inside a group.

Comment: Have you tried using the live paint bucket to colour them?